# DBMS_SQL.PARSE Overloaded CLOB version Not Working

Tags: dynamic-sql, clob, oracle12c

as oracle database 12c documentation states that dbms_sql.parse has overloaded version which accepts CLOB DataType.

But if i pass clob to dbms_sql.parse overload then it give me error of PLS-00172: string literal too long. I am stucked with this have no clue. what i am doing wrong ?

**this is example only what i am doing.**

```
PROCEDURE Execute_Dynamic(stmt IN CLOB)
AS
    cur INTEGER;
    ret INTEGER;
    ret_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
    Invalid_Value_Ex EXCEPTION;  

BEGIN
    cur := SYS.DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
    SYS.DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cur, stmt  ,DBMS_SQL.native);
```

--this is where its giving error PLS-00172: string literal too long.
 --this is overloaded version which accepts CLOB.
**stmt is around 50000 charcters long and weight nearly 5 to 7MB**
**if you require i can provide you the large data so you can check **

Answer (score 0):

All Correct now i have got confirmation from the tweet.

**Oracle .NET Team tweeted : ‏

> Appears to be a PL/SQL-specific bug since the error occurs on the
>   DBMS_SQL.PARSE call

**

Thanks everyone who atleast reviewed the question.